# Standard Application profileActionOverride Retrieval

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, flexipages

Normally `profileActionOverride` entries are available in `CustomApplication` metadata.

However, when I try to retrieve a standard application, e.g.

```
<types>
    <members>standard__ServiceConsole</members>
    <name>CustomApplication</name>
</types>
```

...I don't get any `profileActionOverride` metadata.  How do I retrieve it?

Comment: what's the change you actually made? If you set a flexipage as the org default, that would show up in the object metadata. Otherwise, I would double check you're pulling the right application. `standard__ServiceConsole` is for Classic whereas `standard__LightningService` is for Lightning.

Comment: Thanks Kris, you're right im retrieving the wrong app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you're pulling the wrong standard app as their label and Developer Name aren't always clear as now there's ones from Classic and Lightning. Making sure you're grabbing the right one can be confirmed by going to

`Setup --> App Manager`

and looking at the `Developer Name`. Just prefix that with `standrd__` for standard apps. There's an `App Type` that'll help confirm whether it's for Classic/Lightning as well as a `Visible` column.

[image]

For reference

1. Lightning Service Console = `standard__LightningService`
2. Lightning Sales Console  = `standard__LightningSalesConsole`
3. Lightning Sales = `standard__LightningSales`